# React setState(null) and force update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So with react 16 `setState(null)` does not trigger an update

[docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html?source=post_page-----62ae8ac164c2----------------------):

> Calling setState with null no longer triggers an update. This allows
>   you to decide in an updater function if you want to re-render.

However I need to set the state `null` and update the component. How can I do this?
I tried the following - non of them work.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(null);
....
....
// neither of the following statements update the component
setState(null) 
setState(() => {return null});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some dummy state to force an update when using hooks. Do consider working around the need to imperatively force a state update where possible.

```
function useForceUpdate() {
  const [i, setI] = React.useState(0)
  return React.useCallback(() => setI(i => i + 1), [])
}

function F() {
  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate()
  ....
  forceUpdate()
}
```

Comment: hmm, I see that this updates the component.. but I really want my state to become `null` again... My problem is that I have a form which renders nicely with its inputs being null.. when I set the input to an empty string the help text ist gone..

Comment: you should use a different value to 'null' for empty values, then.. undefined should be fine.